# LINQ restore order post-parallel-processing

Tags: linq, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Is it possible to parallelize a LINQ processing chain but then post-processing stitch together the results in the original order ?

So for this pipeline :

```
var results = 
_fileReader.ReadFiles(inFolder)         
            .OrderBy(s => s.CreateDate).ThenBy(s => s.FileName)
            .Select(s => new ProcessedFile(s, isWriteSuccessful: ExecuteWrite(s, connectionString, logger)));
```

1. read all files from a folder,
2. order them chronologically,
3. then for each file in order

> (a) perform some processing logic ( such as extract messages )
>   (b) write results to db

NOTE : in this particular case it's important to process the files chronologically so that the SQL `IDENTITY` ID is assigned in chronological order

But if specify parallel processing, then testing shows that the order in which files are written is non-deterministic :

```
_fileReader.ReadFiles(inFolder)
           .AsParallel()
           .OrderBy(s => s.CreateDate).ThenBy(s => s.FileName)
           .Select(s => new ProcessedFile(s, isWriteSuccessful: ExecuteWrite(s, connectionString, logger)));
```

But perhaps there is some way to force the post-parallel-processing resultset to be cached and once all file processing is complete, stitch it back together in the original order (as per the `OrderBy`) ?

Comment: I'd recommend including whatever you want to order by in the database record. The purpose of an identity column is just to generate IDs, not for it to have any specific meaning (such as indicating the order of dates on files.) It shouldn't matter in which order they are inserted.

Comment: @ScottHannen I actually agree with you but I'm dealing with a client requirement that the `IDENTITY` generated IDs correspond to the files chronological order

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like this to create a collection of items that contains the original values and their original sequence:

```
public class Sequenced<T>
{
    public int Sequence { get; }
    public T Value { get; }

    internal Sequenced(int sequence, T value)
    {
        Sequence = sequence;
        Value = value;
    }
}

public static class SequencedExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Sequenced<T>> AsSequenced<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        var sequence = -1;
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return new Sequenced<T>(++sequence, item);
        }
    }
}
```

Now this will give you a collection that can be re-sorted back to its original sequence:

```
var files = _fileReader.ReadFiles(inFolder)         
        .OrderBy(s => s.CreateDate).ThenBy(s => s.FileName)
        .AsSequenced();
```

When you're done, order the items by `Sequence` and then insert into the database.

Comment: Can also use a Tuple/Value tuple and `.Select((item, i) => ...)` to obtain the index.

Comment: But this doesn't solve the main issue, which is that parallel processing doesn't generate database ID values in the right order --because that's simply not possible.

Comment: @GertArnold - That was addressed in the comments to the OP. It's requirement of the client. The sequence is determined before the parallel processing. The question was how to restore that sequence after the parallel processing.

Comment: *how to restore that sequence after the parallel processing* -- But it's just an ordering after files were *read*, not how they are *written*. And that's the main issue. The sequence has nothing to do with the actual sequence in the database. The only thing OP can do, when the client insist on their absurd requirement, is to process the files sequentially, which doesn't require any tricks to preserve sequence.

Comment: The answer is applicable beyond just the OP's specific scenario, too. There might be reasons why someone orders something, needs to do parallel processing, and then needs to restore the original sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> testing shows that the order in which files are written is non-deterministic

It took me some time to get what you're saying here. Of course the result of `OrderBy`, even when in parallel, is deterministic, otherwise the method would be useless and not part of the framework. However, the the result of a parallel `OrderBy` is still a parallel query. That means that subsequent LINQ methods are executed in parallel but the PLINQ framework ensures that their output is still ordered. Which means: in the `Select` call the individual items are processed in a non-deterministic order, but its results are ordered by date and name.

This can be demonstrated by a simple program:

A function:

```cs
int GetKey(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine(id);
    return id;
}
```

A few lines of code:

```cs
var items = Enumerable.Range(1,10);
items = items.AsParallel().OrderBy(i => i).Select(i => GetKey(i)).ToList();
```

The console output from the function comes in any possible order, but the end result is always a neatly ordered list.

So now it's clear why writing the files in the `Select` function...

> ```
> s => new ProcessedFile(s, isWriteSuccessful: ExecuteWrite(s, connectionString, logger))
> ```

...even after `OrderBy` never ensures a processing order.

But before going into that, let me mention that even without your issue there are reasons not to use `Select` this way.

LINQ is based on the functional programming paradigm. One rule of which is not to cause side effects in functions. A side effect can be defined loosely as reading or writing state outside the function. (Even my little function above isn't pure in this respect.)

One reason is that a function doesn't actually *do* anything. It's just a definition of something that can be done *any time* —or never. In LINQ this is referred to as *deferred execution*. So it's risky to rely on any external state at execution time.

Thus, your statement `var results = _fileReader.ReadFiles(inFolder)...` doesn't do anything either. In theory, you might forget to execute it altogether (by never calling `ToList` or doing a `foreach`), or even inadvertently execute it twice, for example by first executing it and then listing `result` in a UI.

A LINQ statement with side effects is bugs waiting to happen.

**But now the main issue** ...finally.

In a comment you mention the requirement to write files in chronological order because the generated IDs should reflect the chronology. In my view that's an absurd requirement. What if you have to add older files later to fix a crashed run? But in general, generated IDs shouldn't mean anything to any business logic. That aside, it means you can forget about writing in parallel. Because, as demonstrated above, writing in parallel *by definition* doesn't guarantee any chronological order.

I'm not sure how to go about this. I think you should die trying to get rid of this requirement, simply don't accept it. In the end, `CreateDate` determines the chronology, so if you store `CreateDate` that should be enough. And you can keep processing the files in parallel *even without ordering them* which may improve processing time. Just don't use a `Select` call to write them, but a [parallel`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop). Also, I wouldn't do the write action in the constructor, but that's a different chapter in coding best practices.